# How to set bot's status

Tags: node.js, streaming, bots, status, discord.js

So I'm trying to make my bot's streaming to be with depression but I've tried multiple things and they don't work.
I've tried these methods:

```
client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'with depression' }, status: 'online' });
bot.user.setGame('with depression', 'https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat');
```

None of these seem to be working the way they should. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

Use this:

```js
const { ActivityType } = require('discord.js')

client.user.setPresence({ 
    activities: [{ 
        name: 'with depression', 
        type: ActivityType.Streaming, 
        url: 'https://twitch.tv/monstercat' 
    }], 
    status: 'online' 
});
```

These are the supported activity types & status types:

```js
// Accepted activity types
ActivityType.Playing
ActivityType.Listening
ActivityType.Watching
ActivityType.Competing
ActivityType.Streaming // Lets you use url parameter. This can be a YouTube or Twitch link.
ActivityType.Custom // Unsupported in discord.js. Will be added at some point.

// Accepted statusses
"online"
"offline"
"idle"
"dnd"
```

Answer (score 8):

`.setGame` is discontinued. Use:

```
client.user.setActivity("Game");
```

To set a playing game status.

As an addition, if you were using an earlier version of discord.js, try this:

```
client.user.setGame("Game");
```

In newer versions of discord.js, this is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

Simple way to initiate the message on startup:

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
    bot.user.setStatus('available')
    bot.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: 'with depression',
            type: "STREAMING",
            url: "https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat"
        }
    });
});
```

You can also just declare it elsewhere after startup, to change the message as needed:

```
bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'with depression', type: "streaming", url: "https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat"}});
```

Answer (score 5):

Bumping this all the way from 2018, sorry not sorry. But the newer users questioning how to do this need to know that **game** does not work anymore for this task.

```
bot.user.setStatus('available')
bot.user.setPresence({
    game: {
        name: 'with depression',
        type: "STREAMING",
        url: "https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat"
    }
}
```

does not work anymore. You will now need to do this:

```
bot.user.setPresence({
    status: 'online',
    activity: {
        name: 'with depression',
        type: 'STREAMING',
        url: 'https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat'
    }
})
```

This is referenced here as "game" is not a valid property of setPresence anymore. Read
the [PresenceData Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceData) for more information about this.

Answer (score 2):

```
    client.user.setStatus('dnd', 'Made by KwinkyWolf')
```

And change 'dnd' to whatever status you want it to have. And then the next field 'Made by KwinkyWolf' is where you change the game. Hope this helped :)

List of status':

- online
- idle
- dnd
- invisible

Not sure if they're still the same, or if there's more but hope that helped too :)

Answer (score 2):

With the arrival of the *new version* of **discord.js** this code down here should work perfectly fine

```
const { ActivityType } = require("discord.js");

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  client.user.setActivity("over you", {
    type: ActivityType.Watching,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setGame` has been discontinued. You must use `client.user.setActivity`.

Don't forget, if you are setting a streaming status, you **MUST** specify a Twitch URL

An example is here:

```js
client.user.setActivity("with depression", {
  type: "STREAMING",
  url: "https://www.twitch.tv/example-url"
});
```

Comment: Its the same exact answer from above. you forgot to change the "with depression" kek

Comment: also works with a youtube url for some reasons