# How to Make Discord.js Bot Status Indicator Completely Invisible like GiveawayBot?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm developing a Discord bot using discord.js and I would like to make the status indicator of my bot completely invisible, just like the popular bot GiveawayBot. Currently, I can set my bot's status to various presence options (online, idle, etc.), but I haven't found a way to make it completely disappear from the user's view.

I have tried setting the status to "invisible" or using an empty string as the status, but it still shows up as "online" or "offline" in the user list. I have also reviewed the discord.js documentation and haven't found any explicit options for hiding the status indicator.

I'm wondering if there is a specific technique or workaround that allows me to achieve this invisible status indicator for my bot, similar to how GiveawayBot manages it. I would appreciate any guidance or insights on how to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This thread should have your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286640/how-to-set-bots-status

Answer (score 0):

Just place this inside your code:

```
client.user.setStatus('invisible');
```